# Cassandra cql select last N comments from each users

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table of following:

```
CREATE TABLE user_comment (
    username text,
    time timestamp,
    comment text,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Suppose the task is to retrieve the the last 10 comments from users `Alice`, 'Bob' and `Charlie`, returning 3*N records. How should the query be formed?

What I am doing now is issuing 3 queries

```
SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE username = 'Alice' limit 10;
SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE username = 'Bob' limit 10;`
SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE username = 'Charlie' limit 10;
```

and concatenating the result.

But this looks stupid to me. Are there more efficient ways of doing?

I'm using:

```
> show VERSION ;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.8 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

Comment: This is actually not stupid... It is more effective to run query on one partition key at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Three separate queries is a fine approach for this. Ideally you would run them concurrently.

You may also be aware of the IN clause, which you could use to query all users in a single statement.

```
SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE username IN ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie') LIMIT 10;
```

However, the LIMIT would apply to all, so it would result in 10 from any of those users. For this pattern, you may be interested in a [ticket for allowing per-partition limits](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7017) (yet-to-be-completed as of this writing).

Comment: Good answer.  The only thing I'd add, is just to

Comment: I think you got cut off there. :)
I would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was going to clarify that the results won't be sorted to their clustering order when using IN, but it does make a good solution.